# Why is it wrong to use admin_print_scripts-{hook} to enqueue a script (.js) file?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

According to [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts), it should only be used for inline script tag(s) in the head. I've been using `add_action('admin_print_scripts-{my-hook}'` for injecting .js and `add_action('admin_print_styles-{my-hook}'` for .css without any problems. I use wp_register_script() & wp_enqueue_script() (and the corresponding  ****_style()*** ) to enqueue them.

A "view source" shows

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href=[...] />
```

and

```
<script type='text/javascript' src=[...] ></script>
```

being inserted into the <head> correctly.

Does anyone know any reason *not* to use them this way, other than a poorly-written Codex description that says not to?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem if you just output the scripts (thats what the `admin_print_scripts` is for) is that you may end up having the same Javascriptfile included multiple times, which can lead to errors on your page.

If you use the `wp_enqueue_script()` WordPress checks if the requested Javascriptfile is already in the Queue, and what dependencies it relies on, so that they are included in the right order.

The `admin_print_scripts` should only be used to output the data.

There are a few ways to make the same things work (you could also hardcode the include into your files - **but do not do that**) - but you should always do it in the way it is suggested by WordPress - to ensure future compatibility and everything else WordPress offers.

Comment: Thanks, fischi. As noted in my Question, I already do use wp_register_*() as well as wp_enqueue_*(). I use the hooks `admin_print_scripts-{my-hook}` and `admin_print_styles-{my-hook}` to call them. I've seen these hooks used in more than one tutorial (can't remember where/too lazy to search), so I was wondering if anyone knows *why* the Codex says not to use them. Again, that particular part of the Codex is poorly written, so it calls into question its *canonical-ness*.

Comment: @AKTed the reason you may want to use another hook is that you could enqueue your Javascript earlier. Does not really make a difference in the outcome, but the later you call an enqueue_script, the less there are possibilities to dequeue the script, if needed. Always depends on what you want to achieve, but enqueueing AFTER `admin_print_scripts` would be pointless ;)