# How do I only load a plugin js on it's settings pages?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, javascript

I have a plugin that is conflicting with some default wordpress functions. In the post and page creating/edit areas. I only need my functions on my settings pages. I have the js file loading in admin, no problem.

Can I tell the script not to load unless I'm viewing the settings pages for my plug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a plugin page-specific script enqueue hook.

### Edit

Best-practice method is to use `admin_enqueue_scripts-{hook}`, rather than `admin_print_scirpts-{hook}`. But, because you're targeting your own Plugin's admin page specifically, either one is perfectly fine.

The hook to avoid is the "global" `admin_print_scripts`.

### Original

The call would look like this:

```
    /* Using registered $page handle to hook script load */
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page, 'my_plugin_admin_scripts');
```

And you define the `$page` hook like so:

```
$page = add_submenu_page( $args );
```

Answer copied [directly out of the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_scripts_only_on_plugin_pages):

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_plugin_admin_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_admin_menu' );

function my_plugin_admin_init() {
    /* Register our script. */
    wp_register_script( 'my-plugin-script', plugins_url('/script.js', __FILE__) );
}

function my_plugin_admin_menu() {
    /* Register our plugin page */
    $page = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php', // The parent page of this menu
                              __( 'My Plugin', 'myPlugin' ), // The Menu Title
                              __( 'My Plugin', 'myPlugin' ), // The Page title
              'manage_options', // The capability required for access to this item
              'my_plugin-options', // the slug to use for the page in the URL
                              'my_plugin_manage_menu' // The function to call to render the page
                           );

    /* Using registered $page handle to hook script load */
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page, 'my_plugin_admin_scripts');
}

function my_plugin_admin_scripts() {
    /*
     * It will be called only on your plugin admin page, enqueue our script here
     */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-script' );
}

function my_plugin_manage_menu() {
    /* Output our admin page */
}
?>
```

Comment: I actually prefer `admin_print_scripts-{hook}` over my own posted solution, but as noted in the link in my Answer, it's apparently "incorrect" (also [according to Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts)). But I think the Codex is referencing the aforementioned link (and it's poorly written, to boot).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `admin_print_scripts-{hook}`, though it would be *better* to put the scripts in a .js file, and *enqueue* them, via `admin_enqueue_scripts-{hook}` instead.

Comment: See updated answer. You want to avoid the "global" `admin_print_scripts` hook. But by targeting your own Plugin's admin page specifically, via the `{hook}` suffix, either `enqueue` or `print` is fine. Though, if you're actually `enqueueing` a script, obviously you'd want to use `wp_enqueue_script-{hook}` to do that. If you need to *print* an ad hoc script, there's nothing wrong with using `admin_print_scripts-{hook}`.

Comment: There isn't an `admin_enqueue_scripts-$hook_suffix` (same for `wp_*`) in core. In admin-header.php, lines 63-69, are the relevant enqueueing hooks (for admin).

Comment: Please refer to [`wp-admin/admin-header.php`, line 63](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L63).

Comment: That line is `do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);`, which is passing $hook_suffix to the callback function.

Comment: Fair enough. The point is still to make use of `$hook_suffix` to enqueue the script only on the Plugin-specific page. :) I should have clarified that better.

Comment: True, which is what I used in my Answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

To make your life easier and coding faster (no core file search needed), we've written the **["Current Admin Info" Plugin](https://github.com/wecodemore/current-admin-info)**.

This way you can easily see what you get back from the admin globals or the `get_current_screen()` function, which you then can access using the properties you see in the additional contextual help tabs.

```
// See dump
var_dump( get_current_screen()->property );

# @example
// Get the post type
$post_type = get_current_screen()->post_type;
// Get the current parent_file (main menu entry that meets for every submenu)
$parent = get_current_screen()->parent_file;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't yet understand why, but [according to Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts), you should *only* use `admin_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue styles/scripts in the admin. I have an [open Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81783/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-admin-print-scripts-hook-to-enqueue-a-script-js-file) asking why, but haven't yet received a satisfactory answer. The Codex entry might be in reference to [this core dev's post](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/).

Here's how to do it the "correct" way (note: the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook should only be called from another hooked function, e.g., as I've done in the second code block with `admin_menu`. If you try to hook `admin_enqueue_scripts` too early, you'll get errors):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'YOUR_ENQUEUEING_FUNCTION');
function YOUR_ENQUEUEING_FUNCTION($hook_suffix) {
    global $my_menu_hook_akt;

    // exit function if not on my own options page!
    // $my_menu_hook_akt is generated when creating the options page, e.g.,
    // $my_menu_hook_akt = add_menu_page(...), add_submenu_page(...), etc
    if ($hook_suffix != $my_menu_hook_akt) return;

    $handle = 'my_js';
    wp_register_script($handle, 'http://example.com/path/to/my-javascript.js');
    wp_enqueue_script($handle);
} // function YOUR_ENQUEUEING_FUNCTION
```

Below is a fully functional plugin to play around with; it does nothing except inject your javascript file into the <head> of *only* your options page -

```
<?php
// Plugin Name:0-Menu Test
global $my_menu_hook_akt;

add_action('admin_menu', 'create_menu_akt');
function create_menu_akt() {
    global $my_menu_hook_akt;
    $my_menu_hook_akt = add_menu_page(
        'My Cool Plugin\'s Title',
        'My Cool Plugin\'s Name',
        'manage_options',
        'my-cool-plugins-slug',
        'draw_options_page_akt'
    );
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_only_on_my_page_akt');
} // function create_menu_akt


function enqueue_only_on_my_page_akt($hook_suffix) {
    global $my_menu_hook_akt;

    // exit function if not on my own options page!
    // $my_menu_hook_akt is generated when creating the options page, e.g.,
    // $my_menu_hook_akt = add_menu_page(...), add_submenu_page(...), etc
    if ($hook_suffix != $my_menu_hook_akt) return;

    $handle = 'my_js';
    wp_register_script($handle, 'http://example.com/path/to/my-javascript.js');
    wp_enqueue_script($handle);
} // function enqueue_only_on_my_page_akt


function draw_options_page_akt() {
    // draw your options page
} // function draw_options_page_akt
```

Comment: Please note that `admin_print_scripts` and `admin_print_scripts-{hook}` are not the same thing, and that the latter does not bear all the caveats of the former. But it is certainly best practice to use `enqueue` hooks to *enqueue*, and `print` hooks for when you need explicitly to *print*.

Comment: They are all three identical in execution, though. except `admin-print-scripts-$hook_suffix` is called one line after `admin_enqueue_scripts` and one line prior to `admin-print-scripts` in core (admin-header.php). Hence my confusion as why `admin_print_styles` is listed as the wrong way to do it in Codex.

Comment: Indeed they are - which is why I disagree with the assertion that it is any better or worse to use any of the three, when one is careful to ensure that `{hook_suffix}` is used to output only on the Plugin's specific admin page. :)

Comment: I completely agree! My only concern is that since a core dev had metioned to use admin_enqueue_scripts (in link in my Answer) future WP versions might change when the various hooks are executed. Or, that post could've been re: a then-core usage that's been "fixed" in a version after that post.